# What would this command do: "find . -ls \( pattern \)"?

Tags: command-line, find

I know what the find command is for but I can't figure out the parentheses are for. Please explain.

Comment: I'd say they make no sense, but I might be wrong...

Comment: The pattern includes parenthesis. It looks for `(pattern)`.

Comment: @Pilot6 the search pattern may not be placed after `-ls` though. It's also not specified what kind of pattern it would be (e.g. `-name`, `-iname`, `-regex`, `-path`, ...)

Answer (score 7):

That is a feature of `find` that lets you group different tests together. For example:

```
find . \( -name foo -or -name bar -o -name baz \) -size +1M
```

The parentheses need to be escaped (`\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)`) because parentheses are special characters for the shell (they are usied to run commands in [subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)), so they need to be escaped in order to be passed to `find` and not "eaten" by the shell.

The command above will find any file whose name is any of `foo`, `bar` or `baz` *and* whose size is > 1M. Now, take this directory structure as an example:

```
$ ls -lh *
dir1:
total 2.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 1.0M Mar  7 01:24 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 1.0M Mar  7 01:24 foo

dir2:
total 4.0M
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2.0M Mar  7 01:24 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2.0M Mar  7 01:24 foo
```

There are two files there named `foo`, but only one is >1M in size. There are 2 files that are >1M in size, but only one is named `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`. Therefore, I expect the command above to only return `dir2/foo` as, indeed, it does:

```
$ find . \( -name foo -or -name bar -o -name baz \) -size +1M
./dir2/foo
```

OK, but what if I run it without the parentheses?

```
$ find .  -name foo -or -name bar -o -name baz  -size +1M
./dir2/foo
./dir1/bar
./dir1/foo
```

That finds me all files named `foo`, all files named `bar` and all files named `bar` *whose size is > 1M*. So, the `bar` and `foo` in `dir1` are returned even though their size is < 1M.

So, the parentheses are very useful for crafting a `find` command that combines different sets of tests. When combined with find's `-or`, `-and` and `-not` operators, this makes for an extremely powerful tool.

What they do in your example I cannot tell since you don't actually give a working command as an example. It will depend on what `pattern` is. If you're really using `find . -ls` and then, after that, another set of tests in parentheses, then they do nothing since `find . -ls` already matches and lists all files and directories.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that backslash prevents shell from interpreting parenthesis as subshell: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html